# ajax jquery update custom field meta value front end

Tags: custom-field, jquery, ajax

There is probably a much easier way to do this. After much trial and error trying to get a postid from a url, I've opted to add the id to the permalink. However I have no idea how the custom value should be updated without a page refresh.

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("a").addClass("external");
     $("a").attr( "target", "_blank" );
 });

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$('.external').click(function(event) {
      // had to add the post id to the permalink in loop as url to postid didn't work
      var currentID = $(this).attr('id'); 
      var data = {
        action: 'my_action',
        whatever: currentID
    };
    // since 2.8 ajaxurl is always defined in the admin header and points to admin-ajax.php
    jQuery.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
           //update the custom field value without a page refresh
    });
    });
});
```

functions.php

```
add_action('wp_ajax_my_action', 'my_action_callback');

function my_action_callback() {
    global $wpdb; // this is how you get access to the database
       $whatever = intval( $_POST['whatever'] );
       // get number of views if we have any
       $views = get_post_meta($whatever, views, true); 
       // update or add post meta
if(!update_post_meta($whatever, 'views', ($views+1))) {
            add_post_meta($whatever, 'views', 1, true);
        }
    die(); // this is required to return a proper result
}
```

content.php

```
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" id="<?php the_ID(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
    <?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'views', true) ?>
    // update the view ?
```

Comment: Note: the [`update_post_meta()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_post_meta) function will automatically insert the meta value if the meta key doesn't exist yet. No need to call [`add_post_meta()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_post_meta) manually.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to output a response in your `my_action_callback()` function. That response will be available inside your jQuery success callback: `function(response){}`. At that point it is just a matter of [updating the HTML](http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/dom-insertion-inside/) of the page with the new views count.

PHP:

```
function my_action_callback()
{
    // ...
    echo $views;
    exit;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
jQuery.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
    // $(this) refers to the clicked link.
    // You may use another selector too if needed.
    $(this).text(response);
});
```

Comment: getting nothing with

Comment: Could you be a bit more descriptive? Show some code? Any error messages?

Comment: Thanks Geert. I've didn't have much luck with  $(this).text(response); the only thing I've been able to get to work is $('.external').text(response); trying to get
$(div.currentId).text(response); do I need to add the id somehow to the function event for it to work? Response is working by the way in alert.

Comment: $(this).text(response); no errors just nothing is happening

Comment: If the response is working, all you need to figure out is the selector for the view count. Showing us the HTML may help.

Comment: <td>
<div class="<?php echo $post->ID; ?>">
<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'views', true) ?>
</div></td>

Comment: Try `$('div.'+currentID)`.