# plugin how to find code and edit it in a template file?

Tags: plugins

I'd like to add an id to each permalink from a plugin. Jquery just returns the same id for each link. Is there another way I can do this?

```
add_action('add id for each loop', 'test');
function test() {
?>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

 $("a").each(function(){

   $("a").attr('id', '<?php the_ID(); ?>');
});
 });
</script>
<?php

}
```

It works fine if I add it to the template directly so is there a way I can find the code from a plugin and add/edit into content.php (custom? loop) template file?

```
// add the id
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
// result
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" id="<?php the_ID(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know *add id for each loop* is not an existing hook I just put it there as I was hoping someone could tell me the right hook to use. 
To give you more a sense of what I am trying to do. hopefully this link will help. I have everything working just trying to port/move it to a plugin. As for re-loading jquery I found it didn't work on a previous code so I will re-examine it.

So its impossible to modify a template file from a plugin? could I reset the query and make a new loop in the plugin to add the id?
[Link](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/35026/ajax-jquery-update-custom-field-meta-value-front-end)